# Maximum current when charging a device through a computer USB 3 port using a USB 2 cable?

Tags: usb, charging

Just got a new MacBook with USB 3 ports. I thought it would be able to charge my Nexus 4 phone much faster using USB 3 900 mA current.

However, I haven't seen any improvements compared to charging on a USB 2 port. Obviously, AC chargers can charge way over 500 mA using USB 2 cables.

Which brings me to question: can a (micro) USB 2 cable hooked up to a computer USB 3 port charge a device at 900 mA current, or is it limited by the USB 2 cable to 500 mA?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Right, the question is really similar but I don't feel like it has been answered correctly. I've read all the comments but there isn't a clear answer. I feel like there should be some Internet source/reference/spec that precisely answers my question. I would rather not have to use a current multimeter to find it out.

Comment: Just because the current answer(s) don't satisfy you doesn't make it a different question.  If you'd like newer/different answer to the existing question, please consider [placing a bounty](http://superuser.com/help/bounty) on it.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Fair enough, but I do think my question is asking for something more precise than the other one i.e. specifically asking for the maximum current possible.

Comment: a Mac can output over 2 amps, much more than USB spec (even over USB 2), but the device has to know how to ask for it. [I very much doubt Apple will put much effort into making sure a droid matches the spec]

Comment: @Tetsujin Okay, that's weird though because even Apple says charging iPads through a computer is slower and recommend using the wall charger which provides 2.1+ A.

Comment: hmm… it may only be 1100mA on USB 2 - 2.9A on USB 3. This isn't particularly clear http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT4049 but I am sure that the device must be able to request the power.

Comment: @Tetsujin You're right, although it seems to be 1100 mA regardless of USB 2/3 for some Apple devices (e.g. iPad) connected directly into Apple computers (not hubs).

Answer (score 2):

Per Apple:  http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201163#12

USB 2 cable is usually limited to 500 mA.  It's about how many wires are in the cable, and the Mac limiting power accordingly (power management).  A wall charger generally lacks logic, so it's full power all the time.

I checked with a variable load, and it seems to hold true (480 mA typically)

Comment: I came across that page too and can't find a more reputable source. A few other sites seems to confirm this as well. So from what I understand (correct me if I'm wrong), the 900 mA current is only available by using both a USB 3 port AND cable. These power restrictions apply to reduce interference when data transfer is required. AC/wall chargers don't deal with data and thus can deliver much more current, regardless of the USB cable version. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB#Charging_ports for more info.